# What battle maps do I use for Legacy of the Crystal Shard?

Tags: dnd-4e, battle-map

I just bought the Dungeons and Dragons *Legacy of the Crystal Shard* campaign. What battle maps would I use with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike prior efforts from Wizards of the Coast, Legacy of the Crystal Shard provides no battlemaps, or even any indication of the layout of areas where combats are likely to take place. So, use whatever maps you feel are appropriate to the situation, including drawing your own.

When I ran it, I simply borrowed some other maps I had that seemed roughly suitable. I'm afraid my collection of maps come from a number of Encounters seasons and other sources, so I'm not sure which is from which. However, I have a fairly generic map with a road running through some hills that I used for a number of the outdoor encounters. I also have a relatively generic cavern map I used for a number of the indoor encounters. I believe the map I used for the initial encounter was from Storm Over Neverwinter - a city wall at the edge of a town. There was also an encounter early on in an inn, for which I used a Gamemastery Tavern map.

Comment: Do you have any examples/suggestions of specific battlemaps I could use? (sorry. I'm relatively new at this and don't want to attempt drawing my own yet)

Comment: @Bekah You might just want to try to play without battle maps then, they shouldn't be mandatory.

Comment: This is D&D 4e, so *some kind* of tiled battle map is absolutely necessary. It'll just be one the group creates themselves, or one that wasn't made for this particular adventure.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs, Well, people have come up with means to play 4e without grids in front of them, but I wouldn't advise that for someone who's new to the system.

Comment: I agree with Brian S - I've played certain combat encounters for 4e without a map at all, but they were a little unusual. Much easier in 3e.